# TSQL Group by Count of duplicate values in 1 column limiting results by values in 2nd column & 3rd column

Tags: sql, t-sql

My query below returns all records that have a count more than 1.

I need to further define the query to remove ALL like ProdNo records that have a TYPE DR and/or if the PN has 91535

Example 137818 Since there is a DR, I don't want either record to show.
Example 137763 Since there is a 91535 I don't want either record to show.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
ProdNo  Type    PN  Timestamp
137818  DF  91020       2012-08-07 00:54:19.000
137818  DR  91020       2012-08-07 07:57:51.000
137764  DF  91020       2012-08-05 23:13:34.000
137764  DF  91020       2012-08-05 23:25:20.000
137763  DF  91020       2012-08-05 22:58:36.000
137763  DF  91535       2012-08-06 02:26:38.000
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Example 137764 Since there is no DR or 91535, I want 1 record to show.

```
----------------Desired-Results---------------------------------------------
ProdNo  Type    PN  
137764  DF  91020
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Query to find Prod records based on count

```
declare @usetime datetime;
set @usetime =  ( dateadd( dd, -2, getdate() ))
SELECT ProdNo, Type, PN
  FROM [ProdStat].[dbo].[Prod]
  -- limit results to ProdNo's < 200000 for Products numbers up to 1999999 and > @usetime
  WHERE Timestamp > @usetime AND ProdNo < '200000' and ProdNo IN(
  select ProdNo
 FROM [ProdStat].[dbo].[Prod]
 group by ProdNo
 having (COUNT(ProdNo) >1)
 )
 order by ProdNo desc
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it for your example data:

```
declare @usetime datetime; 
set @usetime =  ( dateadd( dd, -2, getdate() )) 
SELECT ProdNo, Type, PN 
  FROM [ProdStat].[dbo].[Prod] 
  -- limit results to ProdNo's < 200000 for Products numbers up to 1999999 and > @usetime 
  WHERE Timestamp > @usetime AND ProdNo < '200000' and ProdNo IN( 
     select ProdNo 
     FROM [ProdStat].[dbo].[Prod]
      group by ProdNo 
      having (COUNT(ProdNo) >1) 
  ) 
  AND ProdNo NOT IN (
     SELECT ProdNo FROM [ProdStat].dbo.Prod WHERE Type = 'DR' OR PN = 91535
  )
  order by ProdNo desc
```

Comment: Thanks cjk, it worked! I guess I was just showing off my newbie status. :)

Comment: @user1022735 after it worked, tick the check icon to mark this as the accepted answer. Accepting answers is as important as your gratefulness :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a relatively simple way:

```
declare @usetime datetime;
set @usetime =  ( dateadd( dd, -2, getdate() ))
SELECT ProdNo, Type, PN
FROM [ProdStat].[dbo].[Prod]
-- limit results to ProdNo's < 200000 for Products numbers up to 1999999 and > @usetime
WHERE Timestamp > @usetime AND ProdNo < '200000' and
      ProdNo IN (select ProdNo
                 FROM [ProdStat].[dbo].[Prod]
                 group by ProdNo
                 having COUNT(ProdNo) >1) and
                        max(case when type = 'DR' then 1 else 0 end) = 0 and
                        max(case when PN = 91535 then 1 else 0 end) = 0
                )
order by ProdNo desc
```

Comment: Thaks Gordon, I tried your answer, but I guess I type-o'ed or something as I got an error on the "end" near else 0 . Thank you for your time.

Comment: That is because there is an extra paren before COUNT().  I am editing that out.